# Handle Calendar With Robot Framework

Tags: python, robotframework

I'm trying to automate a scenario with Robot Framework where I want to click on past or future dates based on the current date. Somehow I'm not able to achieve it due to the element exception.

The code looks something like this:

```
*** Settings ***
Library  SeleniumLibrary
Library  DateTime
Library  String

*** Variables ***
${FLIGHTS}  //span[.='Flights']
${SEARCH_BTN}   //button[.='Search']
${BASEURL}  https://www.orbitz.com/
${ROUNDTRIP}    //span[.='Roundtrip']
${DEPARTURE_FROM}   //button[@aria-label="Leaving from"]
${ARRIVAL_TO}    //button[@aria-label="Going to"]
${DEPARTURE_TXT_BOX}    location-field-leg1-origin
${ARRIVAL_TXT_BOX}    location-field-leg1-destination
${DEPARTURE_DATE}   //button[@id="d1-btn"]
${ARRIVAL_DATE}    //button[@id="d2-btn"]
${DEPARTURE_CITY}   //span[.='San Francisco (SFO - San Francisco Intl.)']
${ARRIVAL_CITY}    //span[.='New York (NYC - All Airports)']
${CHOOSE_DEPARTING_FLIGHT}  (//span[.='Choose departing flight'])[2]
${NONSTOP}  //*[@name="fs0" or @name='stops']

*** Keywords ***
Select Date    [Arguments]    ${year}    ${month}    ${date}
    ${currentdate}    Get Current Date    result_format=datetime
    Convert To Integer    ${year}
    Convert To Integer    ${month}
    Convert To Integer    ${date}
    ${month-diff}    Evaluate    ${month}-${currentdate.month}
    ${year-diff}    Evaluate    ${year}-${currentdate.year}
    ${move}    Evaluate    ${year-diff}*12+${month-diff}

    ${shiftforward}    Set Variable If
    ...    ${move}>0    1
    ...    ${move}<0    0

    ${move}    Set Variable If
    ...    ${move}>0    ${move}
    ...    ${move}<0    ${move}*-1

    FOR    ${var}    IN RANGE    ${move}
        Run Keyword If    ${shiftforward}==0    Click Element    (//button[@data-stid="date-picker-paging"])[1]
        Run Keyword If    ${shiftforward}==1    Click Element    (//button[@data-stid="date-picker-paging"])[1]
    END

    Execute JavaScript    window.scrollTo(0,300)
    Sleep   10s
    Click Element     //td[@class='uitk-date-picker-day-number start startSelected' or @class='uitk-date-picker-day-number']//button[@type="button" and @data-day="${date}"]  

Convert Date    [Arguments]     ${days}
    ${cd}   Get Current Date
    ${add_t}   Add Time To Date   ${cd}    ${days}    result_format=%Y%m%d
    ${res}    Remove String   ${add_t}    [    '    ]
    ${dt1}    Get Substring    ${res}    -2
    ${num1}    Convert To Integer    ${dt1}
    ${mt}    Get Substring    ${res}    -4   -2
    ${num2}    Convert To Integer    ${mt}
    ${yr}    Get Substring    ${res}    -8   -4
    ${num3}    Convert To Integer    ${yr}

    Set Suite Variable    ${num1}
    Set Suite Variable    ${num2}
    Set Suite Variable    ${num3}


*** Test Cases ***
Click Date
    Open Browser    https://www.orbitz.com/    chrome
    maximize browser window
    Set Selenium Implicit Wait  3s
    Set Selenium Speed  1s
    Click Element   ${FLIGHTS}
    Wait Until Page Contains Element    ${ROUNDTRIP}
    Click Element   ${DEPARTURE_FROM}
    Wait Until Keyword Succeeds    60s    2s    Input Text  ${DEPARTURE_TXT_BOX}   San Franc
    Click Element   ${DEPARTURE_CITY}
    Click Element   ${ARRIVAL_TO}
    Wait Until Keyword Succeeds    60s    2s    Input Text  ${ARRIVAL_TXT_BOX}   New yor
    Click Element   ${ARRIVAL_CITY}
    Wait Until Keyword Succeeds    60s    2s    Click Element   d1-btn
    Convert Date    21 days
    Select Date    ${num3}    ${num2}    ${num1}
```

The error that I'm getting is:
**ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element  is not clickable at point (783, 180). Other element would receive the click: ...**

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The error that you are getting is because your element is being covered by another element so you can't click the underlying element. This could be because of a few different things.

a) If your page isn't loading then use wait until element is visible keyword. Inside of the selenium library.

b) The element you want to click is being covered by an iframe or another element. If this is the case you can use the execute javascript keyword to click your desired element.